# classes database diagram

Tags: c#, class, database-diagram

I would kindly ask for some help in creating classes that are based on Database diagrams.
I am writing my code in C#. And my main doubt is how to create references from one class to another so that it matches my Database diagrams.

For example, in my Database I have 2 initial tables: `Screenplay` and `ScreenplayWriter`. `Screenplay` has attributes `screenplayID, movieID, description` and `ScreenPlayWriter` has attributes `ScreenplayWriterID, personID`. Then I have the 3rd table which connects these 2 initial tables and this one is called `WritesScreenplay` and this table has attributes `screenplayID, screenplayWriterID`.

Now I would want to transcribe those tables into C# classes. I am assuming I only need two initial classes `Screenplay` and `ScreenplayWriter` and that the 3rd one can be derived only as a reference between those initial two. I don't know how to write these references in code so that it makes sense. Note by, one screenplay can have multiple screenplay writers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Regards

Comment: Assuming multiple writers per screenplay you'd need an array or a collection to contain writerids in your linking class.

Comment: But do I really need a linking class?
I was thinking only references from one class to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb399572.aspx). It can solve many of your problem if possible.

for your listed problem , ScreenPlay and ScreenPlayWriters has 1 :m relationships

so something like below in which one screenplay object can contain a list of writers

```
public class ScreenPlay
{
    public IList<ScreenPlayWriter> Writers {get;set}
}

public class ScreenPlayWriter
{
}
```

Comment: it is just the auto property declaration in c#, see below link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: @Whizzil:  the IList is an analog of the array or collection but with different behavior; it is a structure (term loosely used) to hold multiple items. Saurabh is suggesting that your ScreenPlay class contain a "nested" list of its writers.  The value inside the angle brackets <foo> refers to a class/type.